# Output table to Xml: Show attribute value based on the a specific column value

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I am trying to output a table as Xml. I want the root node name be "New" and each row in the table presented as a `<member>`.

```
<new>
     <member source="STORE">
              <externalId>111</externalId>
              <eclubNo>123456</eclubNo>
              <ssn>195812272796</ssn>
              <firstName>Loke</firstName >
              <lastName>Sjögren</lastName>
              <email>yyy@xxx.se</email>
        </member>
        <member source="WEB">
              <externalId>222</externalId>
              <eclubNo>764746</eclubNo>
              <ssn>222</ssn>
              <firstName>Loke</firstName >
              <lastName>Sjögren</lastName>
              <email>blahblahblah@yahoo.com</email>
        </member>
</new>
```

As you can see, each `<member>` has an attribute called *source*. The value of source depends on a column with the same name in the table that can contain the source value (if value is "StoreEntry" then it becomes "STORE" and if "WebEntry" it becomes "WEB" as seen in the snippet above). How can I get this Xml using `For Xml` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it like this:

Here's a working example. Next time please prepare this yourself ([How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(source VARCHAR(100),externalId INT,eclubNo INT,ssn BIGINT,firstName VARCHAR(100),lastName VARCHAR(100),email VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('StoreEntry',111,123456,13213213123,'Loke','Sjörgen','yyy@xxx.se')
,('WebEntry',222,34234,443,'Other','Name','email@yyy.se');
```

--The query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [source]='StoreEntry' THEN 'STORE' ELSE 'WEB' END AS [@source]
      ,externalId
      ,eclubNo
      ,ssn
      ,firstName
      ,lastName
      ,email
FROM @tbl AS YourTable
FOR XML PATH('member'),ROOT('new');
```

The result

```
<new>
  <member source="STORE">
    <externalId>111</externalId>
    <eclubNo>123456</eclubNo>
    <ssn>13213213123</ssn>
    <firstName>Loke</firstName>
    <lastName>Sjörgen</lastName>
    <email>yyy@xxx.se</email>
  </member>
  <member source="WEB">
    <externalId>222</externalId>
    <eclubNo>34234</eclubNo>
    <ssn>443</ssn>
    <firstName>Other</firstName>
    <lastName>Name</lastName>
    <email>email@yyy.se</email>
  </member>
</new>
```